# How to open a desktop application directly from webpage?

Tags: ssh, putty, regedit

I want to open Putty and TeamViwer directly from my web page.
For example: When i do a  click in 'torrent' link, it then the browser automatically open BitTorrent or uTorrent.

I Want do the same, but for ssh protocol.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you will have to provide us with more information such as the code you have written thus far and what you have tried in order for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert SSH protocol in REGEDIT. After do this the windows will recognize ssh protocol and call any application that works with SHH protocol